# why is my react app display 'react-scripts' is not recognized as internal or external command operable in this batch?

Tags: reactjs

I'm contributing to a task assigned to me to build a download page for our community web app and i have done some things already but I have being trying to npm start or npm run build to see what i'm doing so far but my terminal keeps displaying this error

I have tried to install react-scripts but is not still working

Answer (score 0):

To fix this , first check  your package.json file and see if react-scripts is listed as one of the dependencies in your project.If package is listed do

```
npm install
```

if react-script is not listed do

```
npm install react-scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this recently (not sure what suddenly triggered the error), and the below worked for me.

1. Clean install with '**npm ci**',
   more info at (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci)
2. Installed latest react-scripts '**npm i react-scripts@latest**'
3. Added a devDependencies folder with react scripts to my *package.json* file as below (I kept it in my dependencies folder as well just in case):
   **"devDependencies": {
   "react-scripts": "5.0.1"
   }**,
   More Info: (https://create-react-app.dev/)
4. '**npm run build**'
5. '**npm start**'